# Can not check blank selection field while submitting form using PHP and Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have one issue while submitting the form that I can not check blank selection field.I am explaining my code below.

> addComplain.php:

```
    <form name="billdata" id="billdata"  enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" onSubmit="javascript:return checkForm();">
       <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12">
        <span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right" style="width:180px"> Name :</span>
         <input type="text" name="u_name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Add Name" onKeyPress="clearField('name');">
        </div> 
        <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12">
        <span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right" style="width:180px">Email :</span>
        <input type="email" name="u_email" id="emailid" class="form-control" placeholder="Add Email Id" onKeyPress="clearField('emailid');">
         </div>
        <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12">
         <span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right" style="width:180px">TYPE OF COMPLAINT
     :</span>
        <select class="form-control"  id="compleant" name="complainType" onChange="javascript:checkComField();">
         <option value="">Select types of complaint</option>
         <option value="card">Card Related</option>
         <option value="claim">Claim Related</option>
         <option value="product">Product Related</option>
         <option value="Premimum">Premimum Related</option>
        </select>
        </div>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="complainSubmit"  id="addProfileData" value="Add"/>
    </form>
<script>
    function checkForm(){
        var s=document.billdata;
        console.log('compalin',s.complainType.value=='');
        if(s.u_name.value==''){
            alert('Please enter name');
            s.u_name.focus();
            s.u_name.style.borderColor = "red";
            return false;
        }else if(s.u_email.value==''){
            alert('Please enter email');
            s.u_email.focus();
            s.u_email.style.borderColor = "red";
            return false;
        }else if(! validateEmail(s.u_email.value)){
            alert('Please enter a valid email');
            s.u_email.focus();
            s.u_email.style.borderColor = "red";
            return false;
        }else if(s.complainType.value==''){
            alert('Please select the type of complain');
            s.complainType.focus();
            s.complainType.style.borderColor = "red";
            return false;
        }else{
        }
    }
</script>
```

Here my problem is when i have some value in name and email field and no value select from selection field,  then i am clicking on Add button the form is submitting but the blank selection field can not check.Here i need to check all blank field before submit.Please help me.

Comment: you can use `required='required'` in select field

Comment: @Sachin : Ok but i need messages in alert.

Comment: Pleas check both blank content and Zero index something like ``if(s.complainType.value=='' || s.complainType.selectedIndex == 0)``

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code. It was throwing errors in console. The functions `clearField` and `validateEmail` were not defined. I commented out these functions and it is working fine.

Here is the [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qfuke5f0/1/) for the same.

You can add the functions `clearField` and `validateEmail` and check afterwards that your code is working or not.

In this [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qfuke5f0/2/) I have added these functions and it is working fine.

Comment: @ Alorika: those two functions are already in my code still its not working.

Comment: Post your code or a non-working demo for the same. Or you can check if the `selectedIndex` is 0 (If you know its always going to be at index 0). Another thing you can do is check your console, if any errors are logged in there.

Answer (score 0):

Change

`}else if(s.complainType.value==''){`

To

`}else if(s.complainType.selectedIndex == 0){`

And make sure to post your full time next time.

Answer (score -1):

You haven't add script tag

```
<script>
function checkForm(){
    var s=document.billdata;
    console.log('compalin',s.complainType.value=='');
    if(s.u_name.value==''){
        alert('Please enter name');
        s.u_name.focus();
        s.u_name.style.borderColor = "red";
        return false;
    }else if(s.u_email.value==''){
        alert('Please enter email');
        s.u_email.focus();
        s.u_email.style.borderColor = "red";
        return false;
    }else if(! validateEmail(s.u_email.value)){
        alert('Please enter a valid email');
        s.u_email.focus();
        s.u_email.style.borderColor = "red";
        return false;
    }else if(s.complainType.value==''){
        alert('Please select the type of complain');
        s.complainType.focus();
        s.complainType.style.borderColor = "red";
        return false;
    }else{
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: @ Manik: Ohh..i forgot to add but issue is same.

Comment: @satya ihave checked it is alerting if the field is blank. Can you explain it how exactly you want?

Comment: remove the below code it will work for you                                                      else if(!validateEmail(s.u_email.value)){
        alert('Please enter a valid email');
        s.u_email.focus();
        s.u_email.style.borderColor = "red";
        return false;
    }